# How to get the frequency of the sound to draw spectrum in JavaME?

Tags: java, java-me

I have a problem and I need your help. I want to read a media file (mp3, wav,...), play it, and draw its spectrum but I don't know how to get the frequency of the sound in J2ME. Anybody can give me an answer ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "Fast Fourier Transform" or FFT for short.  It is a method of analyzing a sound to extract spectrum information.  See http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?165183-Frequency-Analysis-in-J2ME for links to some sources.

You can also Google for `j2me fft`